# Epson Expression Premium XP-700

Tags: software-installation, printing

How to install Epson Expression Premium XP-700 printer into Desktop Ubuntu 13:10. It detects the network printer but then looks for a driver but does not find one.

Answer (score 1):

Please check here: https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-XP-700_Series Download the .deb package appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit; check:

```
arch
```

Assuming yours is 64-bit (x86_64), download the amd64 deb to your desktop. Install from the terminal with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i epson*.deb
```

After installation, the XP-700 will appear in the list of available Epson drivers.